# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Tags: python, attributeerror, nonetype, ends-with

I am currently working on a Python script that updates a web page. But running the main script generates this error:

```
<res status='-1'><error message="'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'"><![CDATA[
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file/ws_config.py", line XXXX, in Run
    tests = TestList().tests
  File "/path/to/file/ws_config.py", line XXXX, in __init__
    UpdateTestGroup(None),
  File "/path/to/file/ws_config.py", line XXXX, in __init__
    test = CT.CurlTest(settings),
  File "/path/to/file/config_tests.py", line XXXX, in __init__
    self.params.path = os.path.join('/', os.path.join(params.dir, params.file))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 67, in join
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

I cannot past any code because is too long. What I am trying to understand is where the error lays or what part of the code is triggering the AttributeError.
Can you please help me???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `path` in the `elif` is a `None` and `None == ''` returns `False` so the remain will be executed. And backwards, the `params.dir` is a `None`. You need to check your code where the `params.dir` generated to see how the `None` come.

Comment: The problem is in the last but one entry: either `params.dir` or `params.file` is `None`, not the last entry since it points to `posixpath.py` stdlib module.

Comment: So you are basically saying that either `params.dir` or `params.file` are returning a `None`?

Comment: Yes. `params.dir` is `None`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I'll try to print out the value of `params.dir` and `params.file` and i'll let you know.